# How to convert data of double in to array of byte, also how to check its output that the data is converted properly

Tags: java, arrays, openflow

Using the following code to convert Flow_Rate from a 'double' to a byte array I received the output: `[B@6a2b8b42`

How do I check that the output is correct?

```
private double Flow_Rate= 8;   

OFVendor of_vendor = new OFVendor(); 
byte [] rate = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putDouble(Flow_Rate).array(); 
of_vendor.setData(rate);  

Logger.stderr("ZB---->> ClientChannelWatcher::handleConnectedEvent OFVendor setData() : "+rate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your goal is to put the "bits" of your double into a binary buffer.

If so, your best bet is probably to use a [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
...

private double Flow_Rate= 8.0; 
...

byte[] rate_buffer = new byte[8];
ByteBuffer.wrap(rate_buffer).putDouble(Flow_Rate); 
...
```

PS:
`[B@6a2b8b42` is just how any object is printed - it has nothing directly to do with the contents of your byte array.

Comment: Additional note: if you want to print the contents of the array, three methods are 1) use a "for ()" loop, 2) use JDK 1.5++ [java.util.Arrays.toString()](http://www.wikihow.com/Print-an-Array-in-Java), or 3) use [Arrays.deepToString()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_deeptostring.htm).

Comment: Thanks,
this code is working fine as before i told you that was also giving the same output.
I have also a question,
after data is converted in to array of byte
then i need to parse that data to another function and the argument of that function is of ByteBuffer type, i converted it also by using
ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.wrap(rate);
there it is giving the exception of 
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
how can i solve this? 
If you know please let me know
Thanks for your quick response.